Flutter google map reverse geocoding issues
I'm working on an app thats somewhat like uber. But the issue is that when I want to search for an address, nothing pops up from my prediction ui. And also the pickup address supposed to get the address of the user which the map does but on my search destination page, it does not display the address in text. Here is my code below; Note: I have enabled PlacesApi, geocodingApi, directionsApi, GeocodingApi in my google console and I am using the right API key, my map is displaying and also getting the userlocation on the map.
search_destination_page


class SearchDestinationPage extends StatefulWidget 
  const SearchDestinationPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchDestinationPage> createState() => _SearchDestinationPageState();
}
class _SearchDestinationPageState extends State<SearchDestinationPage>
{
  TextEditingController pickUpTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController destinationTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  List<PredictionModel> dropOffPredictionsPlacesList = [];

  ///Places API - Place AutoComplete
  searchLocation(String locationName) async
  {
    if(locationName.length > 1)
    {
      String apiPlacesUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$locationName&key=$googleMapKey&components=country:ng";

      var responseFromPlacesAPI = await CommonMethods.sendRequestToAPI(apiPlacesUrl);

      if(responseFromPlacesAPI == "error")
      {
        return;
      }

      if(responseFromPlacesAPI["status"] == "OK")
      {
        var predictionResultInJson = responseFromPlacesAPI["predictions"];
        var predictionsList = (predictionResultInJson as List).map((eachPlacePrediction) => PredictionModel.fromJson(eachPlacePrediction)).toList();

        setState(() {
          dropOffPredictionsPlacesList = predictionsList;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    String userAddress = Provider.of<AppInfo>(context, listen: false).pickUpLocation?.humanReadableAddress ?? "";
    pickUpTextEditingController.text = userAddress;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [

            Card(
              elevation: 10,
              child: Container(
                height: 230,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  boxShadow:
                  [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      spreadRadius: 0.5,
                      offset: Offset(0.7, 0.7),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, top: 48, right: 24, bottom: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [

                      const SizedBox(height: 6,),

                      //icon button - title
                      Stack(
                        children: [

                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: ()
                            {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white,),
                          ),

                          const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Set Dropoff Location",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),

                      const SizedBox(height: 18,),

                      //pickup text field
                      Row(
                        children: [

                          Image.asset(
                            "assets/images/initial.png",
                            height: 16,
                            width: 16,
                          ),

                          const SizedBox(width: 18,),

                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: pickUpTextEditingController,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Pickup Address",
                                    fillColor: Colors.white12,
                                    filled: true,
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    isDense: true,
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, top: 9, bottom: 9)
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),

                      const SizedBox(height: 11,),

                      //destination text field
                      Row(
                        children: [

                          Image.asset(
                            "assets/images/final.png",
                            height: 16,
                            width: 16,
                          ),

                          const SizedBox(width: 18,),

                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: destinationTextEditingController,
                                  onChanged: (inputText)
                                  {
                                    searchLocation(inputText);
                                  },
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Destination Address",
                                      fillColor: Colors.white12,
                                      filled: true,
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      isDense: true,
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, top: 9, bottom: 9)
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            //display prediction results for destination place
            (dropOffPredictionsPlacesList.length > 0)
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index)
                      {
                        return Card(
                          elevation: 3,
                          child: PredictionPlaceUI(
                              predictedPlaceData: dropOffPredictionsPlacesList[index],),);},separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const SizedBox(height: 2,),itemCount: dropOffPredictionsPlacesList.length,shrinkWrap: true,physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),),) : Container(),],),),);
  }}

